# OpenSuse minimal server doesn't boot after restart

Tags: boot, opensuse, vnc

I am trying to configure a remote server running OpenSuse 13.2 x64 minimal and I believe I have messed something up since the server will not boot anymore after issuing `shutdown -r now`.

Since I only have remote access via `ssh` to the machine, in order to bring it back to life I have to force a reboot via the hosting company's control panel that offers a cold boot option.

I think that this problem started after messing several times with x11vnc server (removing it, adding it again and trying some alternatives such as vino).

Right now I have ssh access to the machine and on top of it I tunnel vnc using x11vnc. My current desktop is Gnome.

I know this is probably a pretty generic question and all I am looking for is some hints on what to check (logs?) that could potentially point me to the problem source.

Comment: What virtualization service does your VM run under?  It sounds like the normal reboot is getting hung up somewhere.

Comment: It's not a VM but a dedicated physical server.

Comment: Sorry, it sounded like a VM since you rebooted it with a control panel.  Does the service include a serial console?

Comment: No, only a 'reboot' option via a web control panel. Nothing else.